# "I am planning a trip for January" vs."I am planning a trip in January"

Tags: word-choice

I will be traveling next year and I am curious as to which of the following sentences is correct:

> **A**: "I am planning a trip **for** January"
>
> **B**: "I am planning a trip **in** January"

I have been learning Spanish for many years and I am now embarrassed that, as a native English speaker, I am having doubts as to which word choice would be correct.

Comment: “I am planning a trip for next January”.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

**in** indicates that the trip will happen during the month of January.

**for** indicates that in planning this trip you're looking ahead to January; that's when it will happen.

The practical meaning is very much the same.

Comment: The probability that someone might mean the planning is taking place **in** January is not zero.

Comment: Yes, but in the context of the question *as posed*, that's not relevant.

Comment: No, the two sentences don’t mean the same. You should point out the difference to avoid possible misunderstandings.

Comment: @user070221:  I've described the difference as I see it. If you see other differences you should point out whatever they may be in your own answer. Few people would announce that they have plans to plan a trip.

Answer (score 1):

When you overthink sentences like this, you might start thinking so hard that other meanings arrive. For example, in this situation, one might think that "I am planning a trip in January" means that the act of you planning the trip will take place in January. However, normal everyday people use this phrase everyday to mean "...for January". If you are typing this on paper, I would most likely go with the "...for January" option.